# SQLSRV Error when running registration form

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, azure, sqlsrv

I'm working on my user registration/login form using php/sql and I recently started making it again from scratch this time working a little different(and better I hope:-)) i'm trying to use functions but I already have a error when using my first function. This is my code:

```
    <?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: Thomas Adema
 * Date: 15-7-2018
 * Time: 22:06
 */

include_once("config.php");

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$conpassword = $_POST['conpassword'];

$errors = array();

if ($password !== $conpassword) {
    $errors[] = "Passwords don't match";
}

if (count($errors) == 0) {
    $addUserStatus = addUser($conn, $username, $password);
    if ($addUserStatus === -1) {
        $errors[] = "Interne server error";
    }
}

if (count($errors) === 0 && addUserStatus === 1) {
    // user was addded
    $_SESSION['errMsg'] = "Registratie Succesvol!";
    header("location: ../index.php");
    exit();
} else {
    // do something with all the errors
    $_SESSION['errMsg'] = $errors;
    header("location: ../register.php");
    exit();
}


function addUser($conn, $username, $password) {
    $npassword = password_hash("$password", PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO Gebruikers(username, password) VALUES (?, ?)";
    $params = array($username, $npassword);

    $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql, $params);
    if( $stmt === false ) {
        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
        return -1;
    }else{
        return 1;
    }

}

?>
```

Now it's not done yet but when I run it I get the following error:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => IMSSP [SQLSTATE] => IMSSP [1] => -14 [code] => -14 [2] => An invalid parameter was passed to sqlsrv_query. [message] => An invalid parameter was passed to sqlsrv_query. ) )
```

Can anyone help me because I can't figure it out and it's really frustrating.
Thanks in advance!
Regards, Thomas Adema

Comment: Run sql profiler then capture this query. You can easily find that which parameter is invalid.

Comment: Where is `$conn` set? Is it a valid and open connection resource returned by `sqlsrv_connect`?

Comment: It's set in config.php which i include in the beginning. Here's the code
`session_start();
 $serverName = ".database.windows.net"; //serverName\instanceName
 $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"Gebruikers", "UID"=>"", "PWD"=>"");
  $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

   if( $conn ) {
        echo "Connection established.<br />";
   }else{
        echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
   }`

Comment: Please don't use comments to add code to the question, it's totally unreadable. Shall we assume that the `print_r()` output you've shared comes from the error path after `sqlsrv_connect()`? Is your server name actually `.database.windows.net`, with a leading dot?

Comment: No, there's something before that but for safety reasons i've removed that as well as my username and password from my code.